# Virtual ip resolved to 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have written a server multi-client application. In this application the server only allow clients to connect if their ip is on its list.
I want to run on my computer ten client and to assign a different IP for each one of them.

I was able to add IPs to the machine with the following command:
`ip addr add 10.30.60.100 dev eth0`
I then fire up my client setting its source IP to be like the IP from the above command - But when the server does does getpeername it gets 127.0.0.1

If instead I set IPs in `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.30.61.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.30.61.100
```

getpeername done in the server actually returns the IP as I expect - 10.30.61.100 as apposed to 127.0.0.1

But doing this in the interface file disconnect the (virtual) computer from the lan. (only the virtual machine not the host)

What can I do to have 10 virtual IPs on a virtual box ubuntu hosted on a Windows 7 and still having the ubuntu guest maintaining a lan connection.

Comment: Did you look up at this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61093/change-remote-host-ip-address-without-losing-control-linux

Comment: The first method actually works if the server is on a different computer. That is getpeername actually returns the virtual ip if it is on a different computer.